# Will the network interface change between different operating systems?

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-interface

I am interested to know if the network interface name (eth0, eth1, ..) associated with each physical ethernet card will change depending on what OS you use. If it is constant how does it assign the same name each time?

Comment: Which operating systems are we talking about exactly!

Comment: Just Linux in general.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad, so I'll try and give you a broad answer that covers it...

It's up to the OS to name the device; so what name it's given is decided by the OS, based on however the OS decides to do it.

Different OS platforms (Windows vs. Linux, for example) scan for and detect hardware in different ways, and often use different naming conventions.

How the motherboard presents the devices, and in which order, can/will also affect how the OS names/designates them.

So you can't depend on them being the same, even if they often are.